# How Can I pass ConstraintValidatorContext Interface as a parameter?

Tags: java, validation, javax

I am using a validator class that implements javax.validation.ConstraintValidator.

When I call method isValid() method, I need to pass two parameters, String and Interface. This method is as shown below.

```
public boolean isValid(String text, ConstraintValidatorContext context){
}
```

I don't want to create another class that implements ConstraintValidatorContext Interface and also don't want to use Anonymous Inner Type or another method.
Is there any other way?

Comment: Since `ConstraintValidatorContext` is no SAM type you have to stick with an anonymous or an explicit class.

Comment: have you read the documentation? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidatorContext.html

Comment: @khriskooper Yes, I already read documentation.

Comment: @Flown So, there is no other ways?

Comment: No other way to do what? What do you want to happen? You can create a SAM interface from not SAM with default methods and then use lambdas.

Comment: I am sorry I don't have much knowledge about that. Can I get some reference.